# Installing latest gnuplot on Debian Stretch for a single user

Tags: debian, software-installation, gnuplot

Is there an easy way to install the latest gnuplot on Debian stable without backports? Ideally as a local self-consistent installation that would not interfere with the rest of the system. Is it sufficient to:

```
./configure --prefix=~/.local
```

to have it installed into `~/.local/gnuplot`? Are there any dependency issues to expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `--prefix=~/.local` will install the program into `~/.local` and subdirectories (`~/.local/bin`, `~/.local/share` etc.); if you want it to go into `~/.local/gnuplot`, you’ll have to specify `--prefix=~/.local/gnuplot` in full.

Apart from that, you shouldn’t run into dependency issues, all the required build-dependencies are available in Debian 9. `apt build-dep gnuplot` will install them for you (as defined in Debian 9, but the `gnuplot` build-dependencies defined there are sufficient for the latest version too).